# ffmpeg - bash script fadeout audio file

Tags: bash, audio, ffmpeg

I am trying to write a bash script to get the duration of an audiofile and then apply a 5 second fade-out.

```
#!/bin/bash

f="$*" # all args
p="${f##*/}" # file
fn="${p%.*}" # name only
e="${p##*.}" # extension

echo
echo $f
echo $p
echo $fn
echo $e
echo


_t=$(ffmpeg -i "$f" 2>&1 | grep "Duration" | grep -o " [0-9:.]*, " )


ffmpeg -i "$f" -af "afade=t=out:st=$_t:d=500" "$fn $sec sec fade-out.$e"
```

I getting an Invalid argument error.

Comment: Put a `set -x` on top of the script and try to debug with the additional information you are getting

Comment: $sec is not defined.

Comment: The console output from `ffmpeg` is intended only for human eyes. It is not guaranteed to be consistent enough to be machine parsed. [Get the duration directly from `ffprobe`](http://trac.ffmpeg.org/wiki/FFprobeTips#Duration), and then you can avoid using the two `grep` processes.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for all the help - here is my solution. Pretty sure there are more elegant ways, but I am a beginner.

```
#!/bin/bash
f="$*" # all args
p="${f##*/}" # file
fn="${p%.*}_fade" # name only
e="${p##*.}" # extension
sec="5"

dur=$(ffprobe -v error -show_entries format=duration -of default=noprint_wrappers=1:nokey=1 "$f")
t=$(echo "$dur - $sec" | bc)

ffmpeg -i "$f" -af "afade=t=out:st=$t:d=5" "$fn $sec sec.$e"
```